# Is it possible to get the "Dragon rend" shout without killing Alduin?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm at the point where I can fight and beat Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim but I don't really want to finish the game yet

Comment: 'One does not simply beat Skyrim'. If you hurry all quests and rush the entire game on difficulty Novice you still have 100+ hours of content.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid I'm assuming you mean only the main storyline with "all quests"?

Comment: @Parrotmaster the main storyline can be completed in a few hours (probaby less than 2) and is actually pretty short compared to the other story lines. With all quests I mean literally all quests and story lines in the game; all content.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it is possible to learn Dragonrend without beating Alduin. However you do have to finish a majority of the main quest.

[Dragonrend](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragonrend) is learned during the [Alduin's Bane](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Alduin%27s_Bane) quest, where you travel temporarily back in time to see how Alduin was captured the first time around. Once you've completed this quest, there's only four more story quests to finish before you're done.

Comment: Also note that you do fight Alduin during that quest, but it is not the end of the story yet.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to Mage Xy's excellent answer, please note that killing Alduin does not "finish the game".  Skyrim is completely open world and it really doesn't distinguish the main quest line from any of the others.  I've done play-throughs where I finished that quest-line first, then finished the rest, and others where I've never even started it (which is nice because you don't get constantly attacked by dragons).  So, don't be afraid to finish it... and in your next play through try not starting it at all and enjoy a sky free of dragons.

Comment: It is a bit weird when all the guards are like 'What is it? Dragons?' even though only Alduin had popped up at that point (which could be 300+ hours in game). But a dragon free Skyrim is nice :) when you're under level 30.